# How does ListNodes work in java implementation

Tags: java

I was reading about nodes in java .. I found this example .. I just can not understand how the ListNode works in java .. I did read about it but I still can not understand it .. Here is the code :

```
public class SingleLinkedList<E> {
  private ListNode<E> first;
  / ** Creates an empty list. * /
  public SingleLinkedList() {
    first = null;
  }
  / ** Returns a list of the elements that match e.
  otherwise returned an empty list. * /
    public SingleLinkedList<E> allMatches(E e) {
        SingleLinkedList<E> res = new SingleLinkedList<E>();
        ListNode<E> n = first; // why we create a new node and put it equal to first ?
        while (n != null) {
          if (n.element.equals(e)) {
            ListNode<E> tmp = new ListNode<E>(n.element); 
            tmp.next = res.first; // what is happening here ?
            res.first = tmp; // why we do this step?
          }
          n = n.next;
        }
        return res;
     }
  private static class ListNode<E> {
    private E element;
    private ListNode<E> next;
    /* Creates a listnode which contains e. */
    private ListNode(E e) {
      element = e;
      next = null;
    }
  }
}
```

I do not understand the allMatches method ... I put some comments next to each line I did not understand it ...

First question: `ListNode<E> n = first; // why we create a new node and put it equal to first ?`

Second question: `tmp.next = res.first; // what is happening here ?`

Third question : `res.first = tmp; // why we do this step?`

Fourth question :`if (n.element.equals(e)) { // can we use == instead of equals in this case?`

Please can you answer my questions? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First question: ListNode n = first; // why we create a new node and put it equal to first ?

No new node is created here. A reference is created and it refers to first. New Node is created only when new operator is used. It is assigned with first because we are going to scan through the linked list one by one. Just having the reference to first node is sufficient because first contains reference to the second if it exists.

> Second question: tmp.next = res.first; // what is happening here ?

the method allMatches(e) returns a linked list of all nodes which has element value equal to e.element. Whenever there is a match, create a new node. This new node points to the current first element. This is half complete. Read the next question answer and then try to understand.

> Third question : res.first = tmp; // why we do this step?

Here res.first is updated with the newly created node. Why? Because we made our new node to point to the current first element. As this new element precedes current first element, we have to update the first element to point to newly created node.

> Fourth question :if (n.element.equals(e)) { // can we use == instead of equals in this case?

Nope. Because == works only if both are same object. Here there might be chances that objects are different but there contents are equal. It really depends on how it is being used in the application. In general, the answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the the new node n is pointed at first is because you're going to create a new separate linked list called res that is a new linked list of just the results of the search and you want it pointed at the first node in the linked list you will examine namely the list that calls the method.
The reason why tmp.next = res.first is because we are going to insert tmp as the new first element in res and we will attach the old res on after it.  Does that make sense?  I think drawing a picture of what is going on will help clear up what is happening.